# VBA Convert Time from weird format

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and am working on a subroutine that will help me transform call records into something useful for analysis.

Column B contains values that refer to the duration of the phone call, however the formatting is quite strange. Here are some values:

47s 472ms

53s 844ms

55s 164ms

2mn 17s

1mn 5s

1mn 25s

As you can tell, if the call is less than 1 minute, the format is seconds then milliseconds. If the call is greater than 1 minute, the format is minutes then seconds.

I need to convert those values to seconds (so ignore the milliseconds when they appear).

Would you mind helping me write the VBA code? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to ignore milliseconds altogether or round up / down e.g. should `53s 844ms` become `53s` or `54s`? Also do you want the cells formatting in correct time format e.g. `hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: Thanks, Alex P. Ideally I would like to round up / down for milliseconds. As to your second question, I would like the value to be in seconds so if the time is 1mn 5s, the new value should be 65. If the value is 53s 844ms, the new value should be 54. Let me know if you need any more clarification. Ben

Comment: Thanks pnuts. Yes, that formula works and I have a similar formula in place, however I'm really looking for the VBA code that I can add to a sub routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Function ConvertTime(ByVal sTime As String) As Date

    Dim vaSplit As Variant
    Dim lSeconds As Long
    Dim lMinutes As Long

    Const sSEC As String = "s"
    Const sMIN As String = "mn"

    vaSplit = Split(sTime, Space(1))

    If Right$(vaSplit(0), 1) = "s" Then
        lSeconds = Val(Replace(vaSplit(0), sSEC, vbNullString))
    Else
        lSeconds = Val(Replace(vaSplit(1), sSEC, vbNullString))
        lMinutes = Val(Replace(vaSplit(0), sMIN, vbNullString))
    End If

    ConvertTime = TimeSerial(0, lMinutes, lSeconds)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the note. I didn't know how to do it!